# Finding a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot understand this question:

"Find a linear equation (and parametrics) to $v$ where $v$ is perpendicular to the line segment of the extremes $(1,2,1)$ and $B$ $(1,8, -5)$, dividing it in half."

Comment: That *is* a strange way to phrase the question. My best guess is that it asks you to parametrize the *plane* which is (a) perpendicular to the line segment and (b) cuts it in half.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question seems to ask you to find the equation of the plane through the midpoint $(1,5,-2)$ of $(1,2,1)$ and $(1,8,-5)$ and which has $(1,2,1)-(1,8,-5)=(0,-6,6)$ as a normal. Hence it is given by $\vec r\cdot(0,-1,1)=(1,5,-2)\cdot(0,-1,1)$ or $y-z=7$.

Parametrically, this is given by

$\{(x,z+7,z):x,z\in\mathbb R\}$

$=\{(0,7,0)+(x,z,z):x,z\in\mathbb R\}$

$=\{(0,7,0)+\lambda(1,0,0)+\mu(0,1,1):\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R\}$

Comment: +1 Do you need me to attach a diagram for illustrating the vectors $\vec{r}\perp \vec{n}$?

Answer (score 2):

The midpoint of segment  $AB$ is $A*B=(1,5,-2)$  and  $(a,b,c)^T=(0,6,-6)^T$ is a direction vector  to the line $AB$ so the desired equation of the plane  is
$$ax+by+cz=d,$$
where $d$ is determined by substituting the coordinates of the midpoint in the equation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No $(0,6,-6)$ is a direction vector of the line $AB$.